# Why does a table update with a trigger when the table has a DENY INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have a records table `tbRecords` which also has an audit table `tbRecordsAudit`.

The audit table has `DENY INSERT` for a specific AD group and a trigger which is used to insert to the audit table.

My question is, despite the `DENY INSERT` on the audit table, a record is still inserted into it from the trigger. The trigger does not use an `EXECUTE AS command either.

I did not write this, the person who did is copying existing set up on audit tables in the DB. No one seems to understand why the insert is working on the audit table though.

I know an `INSERT` within a stored procedure can supersede a `DENY INSERT`, is it the same with a trigger?

Comment: My understanding is that you are denying inserts to a specific group, but your trigger does not execute as a member of that group, and is therefore allowed to insert.

Comment: but within the audit table there is a field "insertedby" which is used to track who is made the change. and a member of that group is displayed in that field

Comment: The `insertedby` column is usually set by your trigger based on the values supplied to the statement that made your trigger fire. It does not say that the trigger is the one who inserted it, because the table would say that all rows are inserted by your trigger, rendering the column useless.

Comment: i know it's populated by the trigger, my point was that the user who inserts a record into the main from the app is obviously able to have their record in the audit table by way of the trigger, despite the audit table having the DENY INSERT for that particular group